# Discord.py how to check if a task is active?

Tags: discord.py

I want to start and stop a start when the user want, but I get an error `RuntimeError: Task is already launched and is not completed.` , how can I stop a task if it is active and then restart it?

```
@tasks.loop(minutes=1)
async def FunctionTask():
    print("Task running")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    FunctionTask.start()

@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    FunctionTask.restart()

@client.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    FunctionTask.stop()
```

Thank you for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting the issue you're having but you should try the solution in the docs

> Note: If the internal function raises an error that can be handled before finishing then it will retry until it succeeds.
>   If this is undesirable, either remove the error handling before stopping via clear_exception_types() or use cancel() instead.

Try using `cancel()` instead of `stop()` and see if that fixes it.